# Recursive function shell script

Tags: shell, recursion, symlink

```
#!/bin/sh

param1=$1
param2=$2

recursive(){
   mkdir -p $2
   cd $1
   for file in `ls $1`; do
      [ $file = "." -o $file = ".." ] && continue
      [ -d $file ] && recursive $1"/"$file $2"/"$file
      [ -f $file ] && ln -s $1"/"$file $2"/"$file
   done
}

recursive $param1 $param2
```

If I execute this script, that it call self (recursive). Why not scan all directories?

(excuse me: my english is poor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't call `ls` in backquotes when wildcard will do and is more reliable, that is:

   ```
   for file in "$1"/*; do
   ```
2. The variable expansions have to be *inside* the quotes or it will all fall down on any special character including space. You should use `"$1"`, `"$2"` and `"$1/$file" "$2/$file"`.
3. Variables are global in shell by default. So the recursive call clobbers the outer call's `file` variable. There are two possible workarounds:

   1. Declare the variable local with

      ```
      local file
      ```

      at the beginning of the function. This is **"bashishm"**, i.e. it's not defined by POSIX shell standard, so some shells don't have it.
   2. Wrap the function in round parenthesis instead of curly brackets. That will make the function run in a subshell, which can't clobber it's parents's variables.
4. Oh, you don't need the `param1` and `param2`. The positional parameters are scoped.
5. William Pusell (see the other answer) notices one more thing. *Either* cd into the argument directory *or* prefix it to the path, but don't do both.

With all the fixes you should get to:

```
recursive() (
   mkdir -p "$2"
   for file in "$1"/*; do
      [ "$file" = "." -o "$file" = ".." ] && continue
      [ -d "$file" ] && recursive "$1/$file" "$2/$file"
      [ -f "$file" ] && ln -s "$1/$file" "$2/$file"
   done
)

recursive "$1" "$2"
```

I didn't test it, so there may still be some problem left.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
cd $1
ls $1
```

you really shouldn't expect to see any output unless the directory contains a sub directory with the same name.  You meant:

```
cd $1
for file in $(ls .) ...
```